# How to remove borders in Xmonad for only one application

Tags: xmonad

This is my xmonad config:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Desktop

main = xmonad desktopConfig
    { terminal    = "termite"
    , modMask     = mod4Mask
    , borderWidth = 2
    , focusedBorderColor = "#0080FF"
    , normalBorderColor = "#000000"
    }
```

How to remove borders when only one application is running? When there are already two applications in one window, the borders are needed.

Answer (score 1):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html#v:smartBorders

You need to set that as your `layoutHook`.

If I understand the question correctly (you say application but I assume you mean window).